# The '.' operator cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group' Error CS0023

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting this error

> The "." operator cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'

When setting the color of the Material.

Here is the code I'm using to set color of the material

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SetColor : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Material[] CarMaterial;
    public GameObject[] LoadedCars;

    public void Yellow()
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < LoadedCars.Length; z++) 
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CarToLoad") == z)
            {       
                CarMaterial[z].color = Color.red;
                //  a.color = Color.red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include `CarMaterial` definition. The space between the array reference and the indexer shouldn't be a problem and it most definitely shouldn't throw a compile time error talking about method groups.

Comment: @Greg That is not the reason. Compiler can handle spaces perfectly well between the array reference and the bracketed indexer.

Comment: try to use CarMaterial[z].SetColor("_Color", Color.red) and tell me if the error keeps

Comment: You have a method `Yellow` trying to set something color to `red`. Compiler is just helping future developpers to avoid getting insane trying to undersand why the car is red and not yellow, and just refuse to compile :)

Comment: Intellisense can be helpful here. Place the cursor where you thing the problem is and press Ctrl+Space, and see what is offered to you.

Comment: You have changed your code 4x and I don't think this is your actual code. Let us know when you post your actual code. Preferably, double click on the error and make sure that the code in this question is what's actually causing the issue.

Comment: Is there a method named "Color" in your SetColor class? If yes, the compiler will assume you mean this method when you write "Color."